# Is there a way to set the rotation of an entity relative to another entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to make it so what ever direction I look a specified entity looks in that direction as well. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you need a super fast clock and a `setblock` with `rotate` DataTag command?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is not. Now, you could have a backup mob pushing the other mob in that direction that you are looking in, but other than that, no.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to test for the rotation of the player, and then set the rotation of the entity to that same rotation. Be warned, that will take A LOT of command blocks. You can use CPdirection MCEdit filter and edit it to your needs. Here is the video about the filter:

And here is the filter download: https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com%2Fs%2Fysfaji16z0qf8fn%2FCPDirectionsRexMod.py&redir_token=TNRwyDPPCDnhZzDEQxU1tejVy_t8MTQyNTg0NzY5MEAxNDI1NzYxMjkw